# Javascript error on Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm facing an issue with Appcelerator Titanium. I have the following code :

```
var navInit = Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow();
```

And later:

```
navInit({window : applicationWindow})
```

where applicationWindow is a TI window.

When I compile I get this error :

```
Object is not a function (evaluating 'navInit(.....)');
```

I can't see what is the problem and how to solve it.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow()` returns an object, not a function. You can't execute it.

To update its window after creation, use `navInit.setWindow(applicationWindow);` instead.

Comment: To add to this. Always look at the relevant documentation first! http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is clear about the usage.

```
var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    title: 'Red Window'
});

var win1 = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window: win2
});

win.open();
```

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow

Comment: Yep thanks I missed out and I wrote : Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow; and it is working now